Annotating a decorator with generic Protocols causes "arg-type" (incompatible type) error involving `Never`
I'm trying to implement and annotate a decorator for functions without keyword arguments (but with variable number of arguments) using typing's Protocol as user-defined Generic types.
But MyPy issues me the following errors (repeated in the MRE above the lines causing it):

error: Argument 1 to "my_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[], int]"; expected "FunctionToDecorate[Never, Never]"  [arg-type].

error: Argument 1 to "my_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], int]"; expected "FunctionToDecorate[Never, Never]"  [arg-type].

error: Argument 1 to "my_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[int, Any], Any]"; expected "FunctionToDecorate[Never, Never]"  [arg-type].


What is it caused by and how to solve it?
Is it caused by the way I use ParamSpec in my Protocols?
Why does it involve Never and why are the received types not consistent with the expected FunctionToDecorate[Never, Never]?
MRE (MyPy playground here):
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

from typing import Protocol, ParamSpec, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
P = ParamSpec("P")


# Callable types (as Protocols):
class FunctionToDecorate(Generic[T, P], Protocol):
    def __call__(self, *args: P.args) -> T: ...


class DecoratedFunction(Generic[T, P], Protocol):
    def __call__(self, *args: P.args) -> T: ...


# The decorator
def my_decorator(f: FunctionToDecorate[T, P]) -> DecoratedFunction[T, P]:

    def my_decorated_function(*args) -> T:
        return f(*args)

    return my_decorated_function


# error: Argument 1 to "my_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[], int]"; expected "FunctionToDecorate[Never, Never]"  [arg-type]
@my_decorator
def get_val() -> int:
    return 1


# error: Argument 1 to "my_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[int], int]"; expected "FunctionToDecorate[Never, Never]"  [arg-type]
@my_decorator
def double_val(val: int) -> int:
    return val * 2


# error: Argument 1 to "my_decorator" has incompatible type "Callable[[int, Any], Any]"; expected "FunctionToDecorate[Never, Never]"  [arg-type]
@my_decorator
def get_val_with_kwarg(val: int, kw=None):
    return val


def main():
    print("get_val()`s return value:", get_val())
    print("double_val()`s return value:", double_val(2))
    print("get_val_with_kwarg()`s return value:", get_val_with_kwarg(3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The output:
get_val()`s return value: 1
double_val()`s return value: 4
get_val_with_kwarg()`s return value: 3


NB:
The use of Protocol is justified by the complexity of the involved signatures Callable can't represent. The above MRE is simply what my problem seems to boil down to when using these tools.
NB-2:
I'm also aware of the simpler syntax introduced by Python 3.12 for generic types. The use of TypeVar is justified by a backward compatibility constraint to Python 3.10.

The main cause is that P.args and P.kwargs must always be used together. You can also drop those Protocols and replace them with just Callable[P, T]: def my_decorator(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:. That said, this seems to be too contrived an example; what is your real use case, or could you give a better, more realistic one?

@InSync Hello, as said in my Nota Bene, the actual use case involve more complex signatures (the decorator is meant to add kwargs to functions that don't have any initially) that can't really be  represented by Callable. Won't using P.kwargs allow functions with kwargs as input from a static type analysis point of view?

And as I said, you should show us a more realistic example. I don't quite get the question; you can already type a function accepting only **kwargs without using that: class F(Protocol): def __call__(self, /, **kwargs: int) -> None: ....

P.args, P.kwargs means positional arguments and keyword arguments, respectively. It doesn't mean positional and keyword parameters (see difference between parameters and arguments). Python has 5 different types of parameters (positional-only, positional-or-keyword, variadic positional, keyword-only, variadic keyword), but only 2 different types of arguments (positional, keyword).

...  P.kwargs could map to any of positional-or-keyword parameter, keyword-only parameter, variadic keyword parameter, and so no, using P.kwargs alone doesn't correspond to a concrete Python function signature.

To clarify "must" in the first comment: docs don't state that clearly enough, but PEP does: https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#id1 (2nd paragraph and snippet under it in "Valid use locations").

However, if you don't really need custom Protocols (cannot make it work with them) and can ignore params with defaults, there is a partial solution: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&gist=90e599be327cd509ae40e8ef9bcba443&enable-incomplete-feature=PreciseTupleTypes%2CNewGenericSyntax

@STerliakov Hello and thank you for your comment. This specific issue indeed seems to come from the necessity to have both P.args and P.kwargs as stated in the PEP612 (cf. this snippet). Can Ts from your snippet be viewed as a way to specify a callable that doesn't take kwargs?

Kind of: TypeVarTuple can be seen as a variadic, heterogeneous tuple of type variables. which are all solved independently. So Callable[[*Ts], T] is something that can be called with positional args, producing T.
